# libprocps : readproc() stack smashing

Tags: c++, linux

I have been trying to fix this issue for a while and I am out of ideas.

I would like to use `libpropcs-dev` api to access the /proc directory in Linux.

I have this peice of code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <proc/readproc.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main (){
    PROCTAB* proc = openproc(PROC_FILLMEM | PROC_FILLSTAT | PROC_FILLSTATUS);

    proc_t proc_info;

    memset(&proc_info, 0, sizeof(proc_info));

    while (readproc(proc, &proc_info) != NULL) {
        fprintf(stdout, "%20s: \t%5d\t%5ld\n",
                proc_info.cmd, proc_info.ppid,
                proc_info.rss);
    }

    cout << "size of proc " << sizeof(proc) << "\n";
    cout << "size of proc_info " << sizeof(proc_info) << "\n";

    closeproc(proc);

    return 1;  
}
```

However, if I run it I get segfault. This is the output of valgrind:

```
    ==6492== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==6492== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==6492== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==6492== Command: ./a.out
==6492==
==6492== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==6492==    at 0x4C2EDEB: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==6492==    by 0x4E43846: readproc (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprocps.so.4.0.0)
==6492==    by 0x400B37: main (in /home/mohamad/Work/3000-myrepo/a.out)
==6492==  Address 0x9ad2de89d83bae00 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==6492==
==6492== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==6492==    at 0x4C2EDEB: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==6492==    by 0x4E43857: readproc (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprocps.so.4.0.0)
==6492==    by 0x400B37: main (in /home/mohamad/Work/3000-myrepo/a.out)
==6492==  Address 0x400c50 is in the Text segment of /home/mohamad/Work/3000-myrepo/a.out
==6492==    at 0x400C50: __libc_csu_init (in /home/mohamad/Work/3000-myrepo/a.out)
==6492==
==6492== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==6492==    at 0x4C2EDEB: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==6492==    by 0x4E43868: readproc (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprocps.so.4.0.0)
==6492==    by 0x400B37: main (in /home/mohamad/Work/3000-myrepo/a.out)
==6492==  Address 0x5409830 is in the Text segment of /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
==6492==    at 0x5409830: (below main) (libc-start.c:325)
==6492==
==6492== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==6492==    at 0x4E43873: readproc (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprocps.so.4.0.0)
==6492==    by 0x400B37: main (in /home/mohamad/Work/3000-myrepo/a.out)
==6492==
==6492== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==6492==    at 0x4C2EDEB: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==6492==    by 0x4E4388A: readproc (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprocps.so.4.0.0)
==6492==    by 0x400B37: main (in /home/mohamad/Work/3000-myrepo/a.out)
==6492==  Address 0xffefffc38 is on thread 1's stack
==6492==
==6492== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==6492==    at 0x4E43895: readproc (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprocps.so.4.0.0)
==6492==    by 0x400B37: main (in /home/mohamad/Work/3000-myrepo/a.out)
==6492==
==6492== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==6492==    at 0x4C2EDA1: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==6492==    by 0x4E4389B: readproc (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprocps.so.4.0.0)
==6492==    by 0x400B37: main (in /home/mohamad/Work/3000-myrepo/a.out)
==6492==
==6492== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==6492==    at 0x4C2EDEB: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==6492==    by 0x4E4389B: readproc (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprocps.so.4.0.0)
==6492==    by 0x400B37: main (in /home/mohamad/Work/3000-myrepo/a.out)
==6492==  Address 0x100000000 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==6492==
==6492== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==6492==    at 0x4C2EDEB: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==6492==    by 0x4E438AC: readproc (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprocps.so.4.0.0)
==6492==    by 0x400B37: main (in /home/mohamad/Work/3000-myrepo/a.out)
==6492==  Address 0x400ad6 is in the Text segment of /home/mohamad/Work/3000-myrepo/a.out
==6492==    at 0x400AD6: main (in /home/mohamad/Work/3000-myrepo/a.out)
==6492==
             systemd:       0    1476
            kthreadd:       0       0
        kworker/0:0H:       2       0
        mm_percpu_wq:       2       0
         ksoftirqd/0:       2       0
           rcu_sched:       2       0
              rcu_bh:       2       0
         migration/0:       2       0
          watchdog/0:       2       0
             cpuhp/0:       2       0
             cpuhp/1:       2       0
          watchdog/1:       2       0
         migration/1:       2       0
         ksoftirqd/1:       2       0
        kworker/1:0H:       2       0
             cpuhp/2:       2       0
          watchdog/2:       2       0
         migration/2:       2       0
         ksoftirqd/2:       2       0
        kworker/2:0H:       2       0
             cpuhp/3:       2       0
          watchdog/3:       2       0
         migration/3:       2       0
         ksoftirqd/3:       2       0
        kworker/3:0H:       2       0
           kdevtmpfs:       2       0
      **continues to print all the processess running ...**
size of proc 8
size of proc_info 888
*** stack smashing detected ***: ./a.out terminated
==6492==
==6492== Process terminating with default action of signal 6 (SIGABRT)
==6492==    at 0x541E428: raise (raise.c:54)
==6492==    by 0x5420029: abort (abort.c:89)
==6492==    by 0x54607E9: __libc_message (libc_fatal.c:175)
==6492==    by 0x550215B: __fortify_fail (fortify_fail.c:37)
==6492==    by 0x55020FF: __stack_chk_fail (stack_chk_fail.c:28)
==6492==    by 0x400BF9: main (in /home/mohamad/Work/3000-myrepo/a.out)
==6492==
==6492== HEAP SUMMARY:
==6492==     in use at exit: 336,896 bytes in 4 blocks
==6492==   total heap usage: 235 allocs, 237 frees, 376,803 bytes allocated
==6492==
==6492== LEAK SUMMARY:
==6492==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6492==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6492==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6492==    still reachable: 336,896 bytes in 4 blocks
==6492==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6492== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==6492==
==6492== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==6492== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==6492== ERROR SUMMARY: 9 errors from 9 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Once I run it under gdb I get the following:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__GI___libc_free (mem=0x57a7587f19463b00) at malloc.c:2951
2951    malloc.c: No such file or directory.
```

Help or pointers regarding my issue would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: "#include <iostream>" and "using namespace std;" do not work in C. Are you mixing C and C++ together?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Works for me. *Perhaps* `openproc` failed